# Can I submit iPhone X screenshots to the App Store now?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, iphone-x

As I submitted my app to the App Store with screenshots from the iPhone X in iTunes Connect, it got rejected with the following reason:

> The screenshots contain inappropriate images. iPhone X is not released hardware.

This raised so many questions. Do they allow iPhone X design screenshots in the App Store now? Will they change the screenshot approving process in the future?

Comment: Apple never allowed apps with pre-release mentions on the store. Doesn't matter if it is a new device or OS version.

Comment: No sure how this raises questions - it seems pretty clear from the rejection notice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**YES**

[image]

iPhone X screenshot support in iTunes Connect.
October 27, 2017
**You can now upload screenshots for iPhone X.** You’ll see a new tab for 5.8-inch displays under Screenshots and App Previews on your iOS app version information page.

Note that iPhone X screenshots are optional and cannot be used for smaller devices sizes. 5.5-inchdisplay screenshots are still required for all apps that run on iPhone.

iPhone X Screenshot Resolutions
1125 by 2436 (Portrait)
2436 by 1125 (Landscape)

Learn more about [uploading screenshots in iTunes Connect Developer Help](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devd1093d90d).

Learn about [updating apps for iPhone X.](https://developer.apple.com/ios/update-apps-for-iphone-x/)

Source: - [iTunes-partner](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/news/5993372)

Comment: Taking screenshot from the simulator adds a placeholder for the notch along with rounded corners. Should the image be submitted with those?

Comment: When you upload iPhone X screenshots to iTunes Connect, they will display with rounded corners. Better don't explicit cut's & corner, However iPhone-X screenshot are optional.

Comment: @Jack it says 5.8" is optional, but what would it show when the user opens it in iPhone X? Will it use 5.5" screenshots?

Comment: @AshokKumarS Yes i believe so.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit after the official release**: The date seemed to be correct. As a general rule, you should wait until the specific device is released.

---

You should wait until Apple officially releases the iPhone X. (According to market news, Apple is going to release it on **November 3, 2017**).

Comment: where you found the `November 3` in your attached document, is this possible to attach any developer document related to this

Comment: yes they're not mention any kind of instruction on that now right?

Comment: @HariNarayanan - yes

Comment: Instead, Apple has announced that iPhone X pre-orders will begin on 27 October, with shipping to begin 3 November.  https://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2475805/iphone-x-release-date-specs-and-price-supercycle-wont-begin-until-2018